# Programatically adjusting width of a Polymer Web Component

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

### Goals

I've got two Web Components that are supposed to be nested: `<cpanel-tabs>` and `<cpanel-tab>`. The `<cpanel-tabs>` is `100%` width of its container, and `<cpanel-tab>` children have to fill it in width, so for example:

- `<cpanel-tabs>` has `width: 1500px`
- suppose there are three `<cpanel-tab>` children; each child will have `width: 500px`

### Partial solution

I managed to get this behavior using JavaScript (to hide that from the user) like below:

```
<polymer-element name="cpanel-tabs">
    <!-- <template> and code for my component -->
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function() {
                var items = this.children;

                var count = items.length;
                var width = Math.floor(this.offsetWidth / count);

                for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    items[i].setw(width);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

and the `<cpanel-tab>` component:

```
<polymer-element name="button-tab" attributes="icon active">
    <!-- <template> and code for my component -->
    <script>
        Polymer({
            ready: function() {
                if(this.active != undefined) {
                    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#contentWrapper").classList.add("active");
                }
            },
            // ....
            setw: function(w) {
                this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#contentWrapper").style["width"] = w + "px";
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

### Problem

It works perfectly in Google Chrome, but when I go to Firefox or Internet Explorer, the `console` shows this error:

```
TypeError: items[i].setw is not a function
```

First of all, why doesn't that work in other browser than Chrome, and secondly, how can I make it work **with JavaScript**?

### Successful attempt, but other perspective

I tried using `horizontal layout` for `<cpanel-tabs>` and `flex` for each `<cpanel-tab>`. Surprisingly, it worked perfectly in every browser, but I want to use a method that will not cost the developer one word per tab (I mean `flex`).

```
<cpanel-tabs horizontal layout>
    <cpanel-tab icon="folder" flex active>Browse</cpanel-tab>
    <cpanel-tab icon="mail" flex>Write a mail</cpanel-tab>
    <cpanel-tab icon="create" flex>Write an article</cpanel-tab>
</cpanel-tabs>
```

But again, **I don't want this approach** because it is harder to use.

Comment: Have you polyfill `webcomponents.js` included? Chrome has nearly native support of WCs, when smth works in Chrome only it usually means you forgot to include polyfill.

Comment: I have included `webcomponents.js`.

Comment: Another thing: why do you use vanilla js `this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#contentWrapper")` instead of `this.$.contentWrapper`?

Comment: I am not using vanilla. I am using built int JavaScript function :-??

Comment: You could use CSS to `flex: 1 1` all `cpanel-tab` in your `cpanel-tabs` element definition. This would get rid of the need to `flex` in the html.